# Proof that infinite lists cannot be shuffled uniformly

Tags: general-topology, probability-distributions, solution-verification, permutations, quotient-spaces

A list with countably infinitely many entries have $\beth_1$ permutations. As such, I thought uniform probability distribution over permutations of an infinite list exists, but eventually, I found that the answer is negative. Here goes the proof attempt.

A uniform probability distribution over the product space $2^\omega$ exists. This can be implemented as an RNG producing boolean values repeatedly and lazily. In fact, for computers, all probability spaces serve as quotients of this probability space.

So what about shuffling an infinite list? Permutations of an infinite list are basically bijections between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}$. Let me denote this space by $X$. If the uniform probability distribution over $X$ exists, $X$ must be a quotient space of $2^\omega$ as well.

Now for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $U_n$ be the collection of elements of $X$ that sends $1$ to $n$. Now because $\{1\}$ is compact in $\mathbb{N}$ and $\{n\}$ is open in $\mathbb{N}$, each $U_n$ is subbasic open in $X$, owing to the compact-open topology.

Since each $U_n$ is disjoint from another, yet they cover $X$, $X$ is not compact. This is a contradiction because $2^\omega$ is compact and compactness is preserved under continuous images.

Is this a valid proof that infinite lists cannot be shuffled uniformly?

Comment: What's a uniform probability distribution, in this context?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio There is no widely accepted definition whether a probability distribution is uniform, but the said RNG for $2^\omega$ *should* be considered uniform. Note that I proved something stronger; that $X$ cannot have an RNG that has entire $X$ as its support.

Comment: There may be an easier way: if you had a uniform distribution over permutations of $\mathbb N$ then by looking at the initial term of the permutation you would have a uniform distribution over the elements of $\mathbb N$.  But that is not possible (a countably infinite sum of constant zero or positive probabilities is not $1$).